# How to wrap H1 and H2 tags with a podcast

Tags: seo, wordpress, theme, podcast

I'm making a website for my podcast and I'm using text to display the title of the show and wondering how should I wrap the title of the show and links for individual shows.

Which practice is best? Wrapping the title of the show in H1 and each episode in H2?

```
<h1>Title of show</h1>
<h2>Episode</h2>
<h2>Episode</h2>
```

Or wrapping the first episode in H2 and the rest plus the title of the show in H2?

```
<h2>Title of show</h2>
<h1>First episode</h1>
<h2>Episode</h2>
<h2>Episode</h2>
```

Comment: Is this for a page listing all the episodes, or for a specific episode's page that also includes links to the other episodes?

Comment: This is on the main page (index.php)

Comment: I agree with @MaximillianLaumeister's answer re: not using `h2` tags for the episodes. As Max stated, `ol` with `li` is a good choice because podcasts are _things_, those semantics are going to play _perfectly_ into any structured data, which I strongly recommend considering - https://schema.org/PodcastEpisode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reserve your `h1` tag for the most important text on the page - usually the large text near the top that describes the topic of the page. If your entire website (and therefore your site nav) is about your podcast show, then your `h1` may simply be something like "Episodes", with your title tag being "Episodes - Title Of Show".

Edit: Considering that this is the main page of your site, if you have an `h1` then it should definitely be the name of the show.

For the episodes, to be semantically correct I would consider using an ordered list (`ol` with `li` tags) instead of `h2` tags. This is what the iTunes web podcast listings do in their HTML. Because if you think about it, podcasts are a list of things rather than being like an article with textual headings.